# Trying to get user entered li from an ul into an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have an input that adds the contents to an ul, I am trying to get the li into an array to be used else where.

```
                <input
                  className="input-fields"
                  maxLength="25"
                  id="ingredient"
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="Ingredient"
                  onKeyPress={this.handleKeyPress}
                />
                <ul
                  ref={input => (this.ingredients = input)}
                  id="recipeItems"
                  className="recipe-items"
                />
```

On another button press I am trying to get it take the form and add it to an object, I have most of it working but I just can't figure out how to get ingredients from the ul into an array. It just comes out of the log as undefined.

```
createRecipe(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const recipe = {
      name: this.name.value,
      ingredients: this.ingredients.value,
      instructions: this.instructions.value
    };
    console.log(recipe);
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should get the data in `ul` from the state of your component, rather than directly take them from the `ul` DOM. When you type the `ingredient` in the `input`, you should change the state of the component, then the component would re-render (include the `ul` element) according to the new state. Once you need the `ingredients`, just get them from the component's state. When you use `React`, keep in mind that performing actions according to components' states.

Comment: Thank you for this, thinking about it in your context really helped me

Comment: You are welcome. You may mark this answer as accepted to make it more obvious for people who meet similar questions.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it is by storing the li data in a state. This allows you to use the data in any of children components of the current one. However, If you want the data to be used outside of that (e.g parent component of the current one), you might need state management library, like [redux](http://redux.js.org/) or [flux](https://facebook.github.io/flux/).

Here's an example of how to store li data in component's state.

```js
class Container extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      ingredients: [] // you can use pass this data to any child components here
    };
  }
  handleAddIngredient = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const newIngredient = e.target.children[0].value;
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      ingredients: prevState.ingredients.concat([newIngredient])
    }))
  }
  
  render() {
    return <div>
      <form onSubmit={this.handleAddIngredient}>
        <input type="text" name="ingredient"/>
        <input type="submit" value="add ingredient"/>
      </form>
      <IngredientList data={this.state.ingredients} />
    </div>
  }
}

class IngredientList extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div>
      list of ingredients
      <ul>
        { this.props.data.map((ing, i) => <li key={i}>{ing}</li>) }
      </ul>
    </div>
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Container />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```